# Any drawbacks of using ID instead of DATE column?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I will be storing the archival users' passwords in the ArchivalPassword table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ArchivalPassword (
  id SERIAL,
  userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT archivalpassword_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT archivalpassword_user FOREIGN KEY (userid)
    REFERENCES public.user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    NOT DEFERRABLE
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX fki_archivalpassword_user ON public.archivalpassword
  USING btree (userid);
```

For each user I store the limited number of the passwords (based on the archived.passwords.limit property). If the user changes the password I am fetching the archived passwords number from the ArchivalPassword table and if it is greater than limit I calculate how many have to be deleted and delete them.

The requirement is that I delete the oldest passwords. And the question is if I can make and assumption that the password with the lower ID is older than the one with greater ID? Or do I need to add the EXPIREDAT column (date), which will be used to determine which password is needed to be deleted (the one which has the oldest date in the EXPIREDAT column)?

Here is the hypothetical EXPIREDAT column definition:

```
expiredat TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT '2017-03-20 00:00:00+01' NOT NULL;
```

And the ID sequence definition:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.archivalpassword_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

Can you see any drawbacks of using the ID column in the described case?

Comment: I did n't completely understand the strategy here to delete the records...Can you add the table structure so that it might give clear picture..

Comment: @javaguy I edited the question and added some sql.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your id column is something like a BIGSERIAL then it has a sequence definition which is where it auto allocates the next id from.  Under normal circumstances the id's will reliably be allocated in order based on user's changing their password.  The sequence definition can however be manually changed so that it starts at a different number and if anyone did this then id numbers would no longer represent chronological order.

I would personally opt to use the EXPIREDAT column though as that will always be accurate and the intention is clear.  Not sure why you say "but then i would have to sort the dates instead of the integers" - assuming you are letting Postgres do the sorting I'm not sure why you think there is much difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you have many users then integer (serial data type in Postgres) is faster then a date and time (timestamp data type in Postgres) column to access the record. Not sure a date column would be good if password changes multiple times on the same day.